# WCF Service reference not working on other PC

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-8, microsoft-metro, windows-store-apps

I have a Windows Store - Metro app that connects with a Net TCP WCF Service running on same PC (hosted in a console application) but on Desktop mode of Windows 8. I have added a reference of WCF Service inside metro app and everything works fine.

I package my store/metro app and WCF Service and try out on another PC which don't have Visual Studio installed so I don't recompile the code, I just install the metro app package and run the executable of WCF Service. WCF Service starts fine but when I launch my metro app it give me error (see the image below)

It seems that for some reason metro app when installed on other PC is unable to find the service reference. I have tried many things after googling but nothing works. Any ideas/hint/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The IP address is a dead giveaway: `127.0.0.1:8733` means port #8733 on the local machine.  Since you're not running the server on the machine where this is happening you need to put the correct target address into your connection.

Comment: @Corey It's a windows 8 machine which has a metro interface and a desktop mode on same machine. My metro app is trying to connect with WCF Service hosted on the same system. So localhost is fine in this case

Comment: But you are complaining that the app can't connect to the server when you run it from a different machine.  Are you packaging the server and client app together?  Are you sure that the server is running on the port you specified?

Comment: @Corey I never used word Server in my entire question. Both the WCF Service (a console app) and Metro app are running on a single Microsoft Surface Pro. I am installing both apps on the Other Machine. Everything is on a single Windows 8 PC

Comment: Assuming that the WCF Service (the server application in this client/server pair) is running on the other computer, you should be able to find out which port it is listening on.  Find the PID of the running process using the task manager, then do `netstat -ano` from a command prompt to find out what port it is bound to.

Comment: It's associated with WCF

Comment: Is port 8733 opened on your Other Machine? Did you try some other port? What is difference between those machines?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Windows Store Apps generally cannot use the loopback address, except for 1) communication within the SAME process, or 2) for development purposes.  From [How to enable loopback and troubleshoot network isolation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh780593.aspx):

> Network communications using an IP loopback address cannot be used for interprocess communication (between two different apps) in a Windows Store app since this is restricted by network isolation. Network communication using an IP loopback address is allowed within an app within the same process for communication purposes.
>
> A developer may want to use loopback for testing or debugging purposes, even though that capability will not be available for customers. For example, an app may want to download data from a web service from a Windows Store app. For development purposes, the developer wants to test the app on a single computer that is configured with the web service locally on 127.0.0.1.
>
> Loopback is permitted only for development purposes. Usage by a Windows Store app installed outside of Visual Studio is not permitted.

In a production scenario, you will likely have to install the WCF service on a separate machine. Note that you will have to enable the "private network" capability in your application manifest (on the client app) to enable local network access.