# WCF and Windows Store apps, ConfigurationErrorsException

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-store-apps

I am getting a "ConfigurationErrorsException" when I try to create a new Instance of the service.

Edit: My App and the WCF service are not on the same machine. The Wcf service is running on a Windows Server 2012.

My Code in the Windows Store app looks like this:

```
 var api = new ServiceRef.MyTestServiceClient(ApiServiceClient.EndpointConfiguration.BasicHttpEndpoint);
```

My WCF Configuration is (It's hosted as a windows service):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="MyTestService.MyTestService"
               behaviorConfiguration="MyTestServiceBehavior">
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8000/"/>
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
        <endpoint address="" binding="basicHttpBinding"
          name="BasicHttpEndpoint"
          bindingConfiguration=""
          contract="MyTestService.IMyTestService">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding"
           contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="MyTestServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The complete error message is:

> The type
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior,
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' registered for
>   extension
>   'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Diagnostics.ServiceModelSink.Behavior' could
>   not be loaded.

Comment: If your App and WCF service are on the same machine, that could be part of the problem. See the explanation in my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783974/wcf-service-reference-not-working-on-other-pc/16794488#16794488

Comment: this is not the case, as this was the first fix I tried

Comment: Do you have any solution for this? I have the same exception now and cant solve it for hours...

Comment: Not a real one, but in release i can press f5 and ignore it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem. The following steps have solved the problem for me:

- Close Visual Studio
- Delete the .suo and .csproj.user files
- Restart Visual Studio
- Rebuild the project

Answer (score -1):

It is probably because the referenced assembly is not part of the ".NET for Windows Store apps" library. According to this, http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br230302(v=vs.110).aspx, diagnostics are not supported:
"Types and members that wrap operating system functionality (such as System.Diagnostics.EventLog and performance counters)."

Comment: yeah maybe in vs, but how do I change this? Since this has nothing to do with my app, but with vs