# Call local web service (self-hosted WCF) from Windows 8 app

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, windows-8, windows-store-apps

I've implemented a local WCF service that is listening on port `8099` for Web requests in JSON format. The service can be tested with a simple POSTer engine in the browser (e.g. Chrome's Simple REST client) and is working fine.

However, if I want to call the same service from my Windows 8 app, I only receive a SocketException due to a timeout. I've checked `Internet (Client)` and `Private Networks (Client & Server)` in the `Package.appxmanifest` file, but it is still not working. There is no incoming request in the WCF service.

Are there further settings I have to change in order to get it work? Is it due to `http://localhost:8099/`? Are there reserved/denied ports?

Thanks in advance for suggestions.

Comment: If this is a Windows Store App, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16794488/1822514) may apply to your scenario.

Comment: You saved my day :) The confusing point is, the same app is working on another device with the same setup. Anyway, adding an exempt works in my case.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WCF Service reference not working on other PC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16783974/wcf-service-reference-not-working-on-other-pc)

Answer (score 0):

First, if you are on a separate machine calling the other machine hosting the service, don't use localhost, use the reachable host name or IP. And yes, check your firewall rules on the machining hosting your service to be sure it allows for incoming connections. Then from the other machine, try to telnet to the host machine by specifying the port like this:

> telnet myservicehost 8099

The response is not as important as whether or not you get connected. If you get connected, your prompt will hang waiting on input. That's a good sign. If you still get connection refused, then there still exists a firewall/network issue to sort out.

Comment: Well it's a single machine and it's not intended to call the service on another machine. I've double-checked the firewall, even if it's turned off, the communication from my app to WCF isn't working. Interesting point Chrome itself is an app

Comment: Its a separate machine... the Simulator acts as a separate machine (VM) and therefore Localhost will not work. @Jerico is correct.